# Is there an equivalent to the WRT54G router for cable modems?

Tags: cable-modem

So my ISP is starting to charge me rent on their (undoubtedly sub-standard) modem.  I've never really paid the modem any attention and don't know what the spectrum of options looks like.  Is there an equivalent to the WRT54G router for cable modems?  What's "the geek's modem"?

Comment: I don't feel that strongly about this, but I just wanted to say that I disagree with this getting closed as "off-topic". I understand the "no product recommendation" rule, but I feel that this is a little more nuanced than that. The question is not "recommend me a modem" or "what do you think of this modem", but "is there a modem-equivalent to the famous wrt54g?"--a specific router, and a favorite among "geeks" due to having its spec opened after its manufacturer was caught violating the GPL. It turns out that the answer is "no", and I think that question and answer is valid and not off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is no real configuration changes that can be made to a stand alone Cable Modem, the model you buy isn't very important.

That said, there were some enterprising individuals that figured out how to hack cable modems to trick the cable company into giving you more bandwidth than you paid for. That is dishonest, and unethical, not to mention [illegal](http://www.theverge.com/2012/6/28/3124410/hacker-sentenced-3-years-prison-cable-modem-fraud), so I highly recommend you don't do that.

The honda civic of cable modems would likely be the [Motorola Surfboard Extreem](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001UI2FPE). They are relatively inexpensive, and very reliable. Because they are so common, you can usually find one on Craigslist for very cheap.

Besides the Motorola Surfborad Extreem, any [DOCSIS 3.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOCSIS) compatible modem will work great.